# 32 bit application working on 64 bit OS

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-7, x86-64

we have developed a application on 32 bit windows using vc++ express 8 edition... Now, while executing this application on windows 64 bit os, we are getting the following error"CreateProcess
 error=14001, The application has failed to start because its side-by-side confi
guration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-l
ine sxstrace.exe tool for more detail"

now, can you pls help in fixing this above said problem?

I followed some of the links from stackoverflow and couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: OK. we are using 32 bit windows 7 os and have vc++ express edition software installed.We have a developed an application and compiled that to make an exe.. Now, the exe is given to 3rd party and they were trying to execute it on 64bit windows 7 os. They reported that, its not working for them.. Now, we are trying to find, how can we make our app(exe) work in the 64bit target machine. Is there a way to do create a 64 bit supported exe using vc++ in 32bit os..  Hope, I'm able to clarify...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398/how-do-i-make-a-fully-statically-linked-exe-with-visual-studio-express-2005

Answer (score 2):

You need install the correct version of VC runtime, it means you should install the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package to the target machine. You can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29)

Comment: we have created the exe and running that exe on the target machine. you think, if we have the redistributable package on target machine, will it work as expected?

Comment: @user1390672 you should be *installing* the exe from an MSI package built with appropriate manifest information and redist-packages. You could spend a couple weeks on MS's site studying up on MSI-technology, and I would highly suggest you do so. Your windows-install world will be a much happier place.

Answer (score 0):

As [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622657/193892) pointed out, you need to make sure the runtime for your compiler is installed, or you could link your [EXE statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035287/static-runtime-library-linking-for-visual-c-express-2008).

Comment: If you weasel out of this problem with static linking you are posponing the inevitable.

Comment: What's wrong with weaseling out of impending doom? :)  Seriously, during testing it can be more convenient with a single EXE than running an installer over and over again. I can't see how it's "inevitable" either.

Comment: If the problem is missing one 32-bit dependency, it is necessary just to install that dependency. There is no need to install, in any sense, the program being developed.

Comment: @PedroLamarão, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean there is no need to do anything over and over again. Just once.

Comment: We know too little to know. Running the library installer once solves it if it's to one customer. If it's meant to be installed to new computers all the time, they will need to learn how to bundle the redist. library in their installer. And learn how to create an installer. When static linking, you don't have to learn installers.