# C++/C# Reference

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have created a C# winforms application with VS2013, which includes C++ DLLs for which I also have the code.
This app runs fine on my win7 64bit machine.
When I run it on my colleague's machine for a deployment test (same hardware, same OS, no VS2013), the app crashes and says that one of the C++ DLL or its dependencies cannot be found.

When I run dependency walker on my machine, it lists the same missing DLLs than in this thread:
[Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

So I followed the solutions mentioned there and installed the C++ Redistable Packages 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012 and 2013, but to no success.

All projects target .NET 4.0 (x86). The C++ project hold a lot of external references, but only to .NET DLLs and C++ header files, most of the latter are from c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include
I do not need to deploy header files, do I?

Does anybody have a clue how to proceed?

Comment: Are the C++ DLLs release or debug build?

Comment: Debug builds, also the C# exe

Comment: That might be the problem. When you download VC++ Redist packages they might not include the debug builds which your C++ DLLS are linked against. Try using release build of C++ DLLs and see if that works, then you will know that that is the problem.

Comment: Another way to avoid DLL HELL is to statically link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035287/static-runtime-library-linking-for-visual-c-express-2008 which has the problems listed there but hey no DLL HELL.

Comment: you could use ilspy from (ilspy.net) to see the problem loading the assembly/dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because your C++ DLLs are a debug build and are dynamically linked against the debug versions of the VC++ runtime libraries used by the version of VS where they were built. You can either build release versions of your C++ DLLs and use those instead, in which case the installed VC++ redistributable packages should provide the correct runtime libraries, or you could get the debug versions of the required VC++ runtime libraries and ensure those are present on the target machine.

If you must use the debug version of your C++ DLLs then Microsoft provides some instructions on how setup your test machine [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, sounds very good. Because of my schedule, I can't test it before Thursday next week, but for sure I'll post the result here.

Comment: After building the DLLs for "Release", everthing works fine. I wasn't aware of the differences of the configuration.