# visual c++ 2010 redistributable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Which visual studio redistributable should I give with my program? It is a console application written in Visual c++ 2010. In the help section, about Visual Studio, I get this version: 10.0.30319.1. I compiled for 64 bit. The idea is to give the .exe together with some third party dll I need and the visual c++ redistributable. Is this correct? Can I create an installer for a console application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one (VCPP 2010 x64):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Note that when you are shipping 64 bit software you also need to ship 32 bit versions of the software (assuming you are supporting 32 bit.) The opposite isn't necessarily true.

And obviously you'll link to the 32 bit version of the redistributable (or ship it) with the 32 bit version of the software. The correct redistributable for 32 bit is http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555.

Comment: Note that if you want you can avoid the issue altogether by statically linking to the MSVC runtime. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398/how-do-i-make-a-fully-statically-linked-exe-with-visual-studio-express-2005

Comment: Did work with the first link, I don't need to worry about 32 bit so it's fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends on which version of the microsoft runtime you are linking against.

Some are statically linked to your application in which case you do not need to redistribute a runtime to target machines, some are dynamically linked forcing you to redistribute a set of DLLs.

In order to find out without error, please use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool to see the actual DLLs your executable needs.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/Vsexpressvc/thread/3a007184-80e9-4e25-b5ad-ff31b028c051 for more explanation.