# Linking static SDL_image in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, static-libraries, game-development, sdl-image

I try to make a static link SDL2 library and SDL2_image to my visual studio project so that I can make ready to play exe. I have do almost everything which are

- set VC++ directories add path to include and lib
- set Linker -> general -> Additional Library directories to the path to lib
- set linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies and add such as SDL2.lib etc.

I just try the previous method from this website but it doesn’t work.
But when I run it still requests the dll and display dll not found.

Update
Now I can link static SDL by using the source and build solution in visual studio by [Trying to statically link SDL in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704602/trying-to-statically-link-sdl-in-visual-studio) method but when I try to build SDL_image with same method its error “Cannot open the file “SDL_config.h” no such a file in directory.

Comment: The .lib you are trying to link with is probably an import library, not a real static library.

Comment: How would I get a real static library, I use devel-VC version.  Thank you

Comment: No idea really, if the SDL site doesn't have one for download, you may have to build one from the sources.