# C++ CLI / include MSVCP140D.dll to project

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface

I got a problem with my C++ CLI project. The software is ready and should be tested on different client pcs without VS 2017 or the "C++ Redistributable".

On executing the program, i get the MSVCP140D.dll is missing error message.

So it tried to change the Runtimelibrary from /MDd to /MD, to integrate the .dll . Not very succesful. I get so many Linker errors.

OS: Windows 7
IDE: Visual Studio 2017
Language: C++ with clr 
.NET Framework: v4.7.2

What can I do now, to include the MSVCP140.dll to my project?

(I know MSVCP140D.dll is only for debugging with /MDd)

Comment: Do not change the `/MDd` to `/MD`. You should change the VS "Configuration" to "Release", it will change that for you and any other option needed.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398/how-do-i-make-a-fully-statically-linked-exe-with-visual-studio-express-2005

Comment: Where is the VS setting ?