# How to Include VC++ redistributable in appxbundle file.?

Tags: c#, uwp, cefsharp, desktop-bridge

I have a WPF based project and I am using cefsharp 71 in it. On some of the target machines an error is coming "Can not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies".

I am aware that this needs VC++ libraries to be installed on every system. Also I am converting my app to UWP app using visual studio 2019 Windows Application Packaging Project. Below are the following questions for which I need answers.

1. **Which version of VC++ redistributable do I need to integrate in my app.**
2. **How can I integrate VC++ redistrubatle in my app** ( WPF based app being converted to UWP using Visual studio Windows Application Packaging Project.)
3. **Can I include some dlls instead of integrating VC++ ?**
4. **Which version of .Net Framework should be pre installed ?**
5. **How can I integrate this in the appxbundle file itself ?**

Comment: The CefSharp requirements are listed per branch at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#release-branches

Comment: Hi, You may not be able to package VC++ into an `appxbundle` file, it is an environment dependency.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT But I can't ask everyone to download the VC++ on their system. ? Anything that I can include as dll to resolve this VC++ issue ?

Comment: @AkshayVerma Hi, If you can find a complete list of dll references, this is possible.

Comment: A quick search and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/ looks promising. I'd also suggest you tag your question `desktop-bridge` to get a wider audience. See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2642

Comment: [I would try static linking to be honest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37402/129130) - if you have regular updates and your use of the runtime is light. Never tried for a scenario like this though. Use the old Dependency Walker application to verify that dependencies are gone once you rebuild with static link. Test with release mode binary. Side effects possible I suppose.