# Linking to the VC++ runtime statically while including static libraries that linked to it dynamically

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd like to (Windows, VS2019) statically link the VC++ runtime to my C++ application. The problem I'm having is that even if I set the /MT (Multi-threaded non-dll) option which should make the linker link statically to the runtime, it's not working. I get the error "mismatch detected for runtime library" for all those libraries which linked dynamically to the runtime. Basically' it's telling me that I can't link statically to the runtime if I have libraries that do not.

I've seen questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398/how-do-i-make-a-fully-statically-linked-exe-with-visual-studio-express-2005) where it says

> If you are using any other libraries you may need to tell the linker to ignore the dynamically linked CRT explicitly.

Now I don't know how to do that or whether it'll work. My question is: is there a way to link my entire application statically to the VC++ runtime when the static libraries I have are linked dynamically to it?

Thank you everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could set `Ignore Specific Default Libraries` in `Properties->Linker->Input->Ignore Specific Default Libraries`.

If you want to link the entire application statically to the VC++ runtime, you need to set the options in `debug` and `release`.

1.Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Use of MFC->Use MFC in a Static Library(If you use MFC)

2.Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++—Code Generation->Runtime Library->Multi-threaded(/MT)